# Curl ends with "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: HTTP"

Tags: nginx, curl, mod-security

I've been following a blog on how to compile modsecurity with nginx, [Blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-and-installing-modsecurity-for-open-source-nginx/). I tried to verify that everything works with creating the file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/echo.conf` which contains:

```
    server {
       listen localhost:8085;
       location / {
            default_type text/plain;
            return 200 "Thank you for requesting ${request_uri}\n";
           }
    }
```

I ran the following in cmd:

```
    sudo nginx -s reload
    curl -D - http://localhost:8085 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

and I got

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.0
Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 19:31:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 27
Connection: keep-alive

Thank you for requesting /
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: HTTP
```

I have been on this for hours and can't figure out what to do. The two solutions I've found were

- IPv6 enabled
- Wrong DNS server

I ran the command in cmd with --ipv4 `curl --ipv4 -D - http://localhost:8085 HTTP/1.1 200 OK` with no success.
I also changed the nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` to 8.8.8.8 instead of 127.0.0.53 which also didn't work.

Any clues on what to do?

Comment: That's because you do not pass any host header. And according your config, you did not specify any host (server_name)

Answer (score 1):

That error message spawns due to the command syntax you used. When using `curl` it should be enough by running:

```
curl -D - http://localhost:8085
```

To make a HTTP request to the webserver you define (`localhost` in this case). Otherwise it will take additional arguments as extra URLs to query if there are not additional options to parse, so it is trying to query `HTTP` as if you typed `http://HTTP`, which simply will not work, at least until you define a specific entry for HTTP host in your `/etc/hosts` for example.